# discord bot voice player does not stop on request. help would be appreciated

Tags: discord, discord.js, bots

i have looked around for an answer but no dice. bot starts and pulls the required thumbnail but fails to stop when the stop command is issued:

```
client.on('messageCreate', async (message) => {
if (message.content && message.content.toLowerCase() === 'play baka radio') {
    if (!message.member.voice?.channel) return message.channel.send('You need to be a voice channel to execute this command')
          const connection = joinVoiceChannel({
        channelId: message.member.voice.channelId,
        guildId: message.guildId,
        adapterCreator: message.guild.voiceAdapterCreator
    })

    const player = createAudioPlayer()
    const resource = createAudioResource('https://nrf1.newradio.it:10328/alfaanime')

    connection.subscribe(player)

    message.channel.send({ content: "Now Playing", embeds: [embed2], files: ['./logo/bkrlogo.png'] }) + player.play(resource) 
if (message.content && message.content.toLowerCase() === 'stop')
player.stop(resource)   

    
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You will have to read this : https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/collectors.html#await-messages its very usefull while working with discord bots

Here I ask my bot to watch the origin message (`play baka radio`) channel for a message who fit to my filter `filter`, when someone send "stop", the function is triggered and the player is instantly stopped

```js
const createPlayer = async (message) => {
  const connection = joinVoiceChannel({
    channelId: message.member.voice.channelId,
    guildId: message.guildId,
    adapterCreator: message.guild.voiceAdapterCreator,
  });

  const player = createAudioPlayer();
  const resource = createAudioResource(
    "https://nrf1.newradio.it:10328/alfaanime"
  );

  connection.subscribe(player);
  player.play(resource);

  await message.channel.send({
    content: "Now Playing",
  });

  const filter = (response) => response.content === "stop";
  await message.channel
    .awaitMessages({ filter, max: 1, time: 999999, errors: ["time"] })
    .then((askedStop) => {
      player.stop(resource);
    });
};
```

Here I just call my function createPlayer

```js
client.on("messageCreate", async (message) => {
  if (message.content && message.content.toLowerCase() === "play baka radio") {
    if (!message.member.voice?.channel)
      return message.channel.send(
        "You need to be a voice channel to execute this command"
      );
    createPlayer(message);
  }
});
```

You can choose to set time in the awaitMessages, or not

Comment: the issue with the awaitmessages seems that any message other than stop. crashes the vc stream. any thoughts what can be causing this?

Comment: Just rename stopWord to filter, and it will work, my bad

Comment: i appreciate your willingness to help. code works but it ends up with a unfulfilled promise error code 288 after it runs  for 10 minutes or so. any idea what can cause this?

Comment: I dont have that error, I let it runs for 20 minutes, im sorry, nothing on google about that neither